# Super interface and super class having the same method name

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, flex-spark

I am trying to create a spark datagrid item renderer. This item renderer extends a checkbox, and implements IGridItemRenderer

```
public class CellCheckBoxItemRenderer extends CheckBox implements IGridItemRenderer
```

When I implement IGridItemRenderer, I need to implement the interface methods, I am having a problem with the following methods:

```
public function get hovered():Boolean
{
}

public function set hovered(value:Boolean):void
{
}
```

since the methods are inherited as well from the checkbox

**EDIT**
The signatures of the functions

```
//spark checkbox signature
protected function get hovered():Boolean
protected function set hovered(value:Boolean):void
```

and the signature above belongs to the interface IGridItemRenderer

Comment: does methods in class and interface have the same signature?

Comment: can you list here signatures of functions? Maybe me or someone else advise some workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the implementation of `IGridItemRenderer` is the more important part, so you can use it in a datagrid. The `CheckBox` provides just the functionality, you don't have to extend it if there are conflicts in my opinion.

```
public class CellCheckBoxItemRenderer implements IGridItemRenderer {

    private var checkBox:CheckBox;

    public function getCheckBox {
        return checkBox;
    }

    //...
}
```

If `CheckBox` would implement any useful interfaces, you could also implement them in your renderer and delegate the methods to the checkbox, which may let you encapsulate the whole checkbox. That's not the case here though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that interfaces, by design, only specify the signature for **public** functions, whereas the function in `Checkbox` is set as **protected**.

The only solutions:

- remove the interface/`Checkbox` class from `CellCheckBoxItemRenderer`
- remove the declaration from the interface
- change `Checkbox` so `hovered` is a public property
- it *might* be possible to change the accessor dynamically using the as3 commons bytecode project (http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-bytecode/emit.html), but I'm not 100% sure.